# Blazor WASM API doesn't work on Ubuntu, but its ok on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, blazor

My Blazor API doesn't work on ubuntu. Well it seems to work but doesn't respond in anyway.

```
GET http://**.**.**.**/api/files 404 (Not Found)

An error occurred: net_http_message_not_success_statuscode_reason, 404, Not Found
```

[image]

What I've got an Ubuntu Server (22.04)

- .Net 8 (8.0.100)
- Nginx (1.18.0)
- Mssql Server  (16.0.4100.1-1 amd64)
  installed in my server.

**There are 3 projects in my solution: Client, Server and Shared. Server is the startup project.**

This is server startup.cs

```
using BilirkisiRaporu.Server.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace BilirkisiRaporu.Server
{
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Shared.Resources");
        services.AddScoped<MahkemeDosyasiService>();
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLDbConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<RaporDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 32;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        });

        services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
        {
            options.HttpsPort = 443;
        });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("tr-TR") };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("tr-TR"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
    }
}
}
```

This is program.cs

```
global using BilirkisiRaporu.Server.Data;
global using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BilirkisiRaporu.Server;
using Syncfusion.Blazor;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("****Licence here****");
builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.Build();

var startup = new Startup(configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Controller relevant parts:

```
using BilirkisiRaporu.Server.Services;
using BilirkisiRaporu.Shared.DTOs;
using BilirkisiRaporu.Shared.Models;
using BilirkisiRaporu.Shared.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace BilirkisiRaporu.Server.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly FileDataContext _context;
    private readonly FileService _fileService;

    public FilesController(FileDataContext context, FileService fileService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _fileService = fileService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetFilesAsJson()
    {
        ....
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilesById(int id)
    {
        ....
    }

    [HttpPost("Create")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Files>> CreateFiles(FilesViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ....
    }
    [HttpPut("Update")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateFiles([FromBody] FilesDTO updatedFile)
    {
        ....
    }
....
}
```

index.html relevant parts:

```
<head>
....
<base href="/" />
....
</head>
```

This is my component doing its oninitialize:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    filesDTOList = new List<filesDTO>();
    try
    {
        var json = await 
Http.GetStringAsync("api/files");
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
                PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            };
        filesDTOList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<filesDTO>>(json, options);

        filesDTOList = filesDTOList.OrderBy(item => item.Date).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is my service file in Server:

```
[Unit]
Description= Bilirkişi Raporu
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/xyz
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/xyz/BilirkisiRaporu.Server.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=BilirkişiRaporu
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my first experience on Ubuntu. So I'm sorry if i I shared too much info. I really appreciate the guidance.

Comment: _"it seems to work but doesn't respond in anyway"_ is unclear. What does work?

Comment: Ah sorry,  I've added OnInitializedAsync(). Page is serving. There its calling for api/files. When checking console and network tab i encounter GET http://**.**.**.**/api/files 404 (Not Found)

An error occurred: net_http_message_not_success_statuscode_reason, 404, Not Found

Comment: Show the relevant parts of the FilesController (especially all routing attributes).

Comment: And the base href from the <head> tag

Comment: There's no problem with Ubuntu. Besides WASM runs on your browser, not the server or client OS. `404` means the wrong URL was used. As for the code, no template produces such code. `Startup.cs` isn't used since .NET 6 and the *actual* services and endpoints are configured by `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`, `builder.Services` etc. Anything you put in `Startup` isn't used at all

Comment: I'd suggest just going through a Blazor 8 tutorial and *not* trying to "fix" anything.

Comment: The short fix might look like `<base href="/xyz" />`, experiment a little. Other hosters like Github-pages need a 'fixup' element in the pipeline too.